# spring boot list all application properties of an app

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I'm having a very simple requirement. I need to print out every single property existing in my spring boot application.

I do not mean the spring boot properties. I mean any single, custom defined properties.

Is there a simple way, or do I have to write a reflection based tool, to find all @Value annotations, etc... This must exist already.

thanks

Comment: Reflection might help.

Comment: which was stated in the question at line 3

Comment: thanks! Please make an answer out of it, so you can get the kudos

Comment: The guy who wrote the answer deserves the kudos :) Glad that the answer helps you.